# why i cant bind gridview directly from ListItemCollection Object?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I'm new to SharePoint List and i need to bind gridview using list item collection object like below

```
SPList splEmployees = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Employees"];
spgvEmployees.DataSource = splEmployees.Items;//or splEmployees.GetItems();
spgvEmployees.DataBind();
```

this is not success when i bind it to gridview contains Title and EmployeeID columns but it success when i remove EmployeeID column.

Answer (score 1):

The DataGridView .NET component provides the approach of [data binding to database table or dataset in GridView](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_populate_data_binding_datatable.shtml), without of complex process.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method. The beauty of it is that you can cache the results as a DataTable.